# How do I make each button drop show the video that is clicked? ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-props

I am passing through props to my Buttons.jsx file.  Each button would drop down a video.  My problem is that when I click one button, all of the videos appear.  I want it so that only that certain video that was clicked would show.

here is the link to repo

https://noahfarinas.github.io/stretching/

Thanks in advance!

**Buttons.jsx**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

export const Buttons = (props) => {
  const { content } = props;
    const [showVideo,setShowVideo] = useState(false);
    
    const handleOnClick = () =>  setShowVideo(true); 

   

  return (
    <div className="buttonContainer">
      {content.map((item) => (
        <div className="buttonSpace">
        
            <button id="btn" onClick={handleOnClick}>{item.title}</button>
            {showVideo ? <ReactPlayer url={item.embed} /> : null}    
         
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;



**App.js**


import "./App.css";
import Search from "./Search";
import TitleView from "./TitleView";
import Buttons from "./Buttons";

function App() {
  const TITLE = "Stretches";

  const DATA = [
    {
      area: "upper-back",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTn89EBKJdM",
    },

    {
      area: "mid-back",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnDuWC40egg",
    },

    {
      area: "lower-back",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-xqKx8oshs",
    },

    {
      area: "hips",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLuvQCTPrcY",
    },

    {
      area: "calves",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37GHTaoknfw",
    },

    {
      area: "chest",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NePr1XKRTLU",
    },

    {
      area: "glute",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRCpceBhcm0",
    },

    {
      area: "foot",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXSj_5pBAKw",
    },

    {
      area: "forearm",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ayhu7TzNGSQ",
    },

    {
      area: "it band",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6Psvd81Hyc",
    },

    {
      area: "hamstring",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJUwEBgxWoE",
    },

    {
      area: "tricep",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaZK9vlSmHI",
    },

    {
      area: "lat",
      video: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V5tSn9oEJg",
    },
  ];

  const BUTTONDATA = [
    {
      title: "back",
      embed: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buF1v8aiTvM",
    },

    {
      title: "legs",
      embed: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRTPXj1Q1U",
    },

    {
      title: "upper-body",
      embed: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kpd9ik93Sxk",
    },

    {
      title: "hips",
      embed: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j42sLnoMkrA",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TitleView headline={TITLE} />
      <Search placeholder="What hurts..." data={DATA} />
      <Buttons content={BUTTONDATA} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What if content  is null or undefined ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in two ways. One way is to have a *map* in app.js on the **BUTTONDATA** and render separate  component for each item of the array. In this way each **Button** Component will have its own state and will show only its own contents upon button click.
The other way is to have a boolean property for each of array item in the **BUTTONDATA**. and then you can modify your  component in the following way:

**Button.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

const Buttons = (props) => {
  const { content } = props;
  const [visibilityChanged, setVisibiltyChanged] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {}, [visibilityChanged]);

  const handleOnClick = (index) => () => {
    content[index].isVisible = !content[index].isVisible;
    setVisibiltyChanged(!visibilityChanged);
  };

  return (
    <div className="buttonContainer">
      {content.map((item, index) => (
        <div className="buttonSpace" key={index}>
          <button id="btn" onClick={handleOnClick(index)}>
            {item.title}
          </button>
          {item.isVisible ? <ReactPlayer url={item.embed} /> : null}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Buttons;
```

and in app.js will have the following changes:
**App.js**

```
const BUTTONDATA = [
    {
      title: "back",
      embed: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=buF1v8aiTvM",
      isVisible: false
    },

    {
      title: "legs",
      embed: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIRTPXj1Q1U",
      isVisible: false
    },

    {
      title: "upper-body",
      embed: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kpd9ik93Sxk",
      isVisible: false
    },

    {
      title: "hips",
      embed: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j42sLnoMkrA",
      isVisible: false
    }
  ];
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-firefly-gxepdw?file=/src/App.js:89-591) is the code sandbox I created to toggle videos on button click.

Comment: so with this, what if i only wanted to have one video show at a time?

Comment: You mean if user has clicked any of the buttons already and then decides to click on another button, then the video of first one should disappear? if yes then you should change the body of handleOnClick method in the following way:
for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {

      if (content[i].isVisible) content[i].isVisible = !content[i].isVisible;

    }

    content[index].isVisible = !content[index].isVisible;

    setVisibiltyChanged(!visibilityChanged);